# Looping through a strongly typed DataSet

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

How do you loop through a strongly typed DataSet?

We have the following defined in the DataSet designer:

```
DataSet name:      DataSetSchedules
DataTable name:    DataTableSchedules
TableAdapter name: DataTableDataAdapterSchedules
```

This is a code sample I found using Google:

```
Dim col As DataColumn
Dim dt as DataTable
Dim dr as DataRow
Dim strMyValue AS String = ""

dt = ds.Tables(0)

For Each dr In dt.Rows
   For Each col In dt.Columns
    StrMyValue = dr(col.ColumnName)
   Next
Next
```

Since a DataSet was already created in the DataSet desiner, I tried this:

```
Dim col As DataColumn
Dim dt as DataTable
Dim dr as DataRow
Dim strMyValue AS String = ""

dt = DataSetSchedules.Tables(0)
```

Intellisence told me that "Tables" was not a choice so I'm stuck.

Most of the code samples I found show that this is how to do it, but I don't think that this applies to strongly typed DataSets.

Can you show the correct coding needed to loop through DataSetSchedules and get the value in dr(col.ColumnName)?

Comment: The name of your DataSet is it's type, you have to create an instance of it by using `New`. Then you can use `myDsSchedules.Tables(0)`. But instead of using the weakly typed methods inherited from a losely typed `DataSet` use the strongly typed `DataTables`. For example(guessing types): `For Each row As  SchedulesRow In myDsSchedules.Schedules.Rows ...`. Then you can use the strongly typed property of the auto-generated `SchedulesRow` class which inherits from `DataRow`.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the reply. Can you show a full code sample so I can learn from it using all the names we defined in the DataSet designer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
 Dim DS as new DataSetSchedules

    DT = DS.Tables(0)

 For Each DR as DataRow In DT.Rows
   ' Code
 Next
```

or as @Tim Suggested use the strongly typed Tables. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A typed DataSet is a class that derives from a DataSet. As such, it
>   inherits all the methods, events, and properties of a DataSet.
>   Additionally, a typed DataSet provides strongly typed methods, events,
>   and properties. This means you can access tables and columns by name,
>   instead of using collection-based methods

Comment: Thanks for the reply AbZy. That got me further. When I reach this line: For Each dr In DS.rows intellisence does not allow "rows" as a choice. Looks like something else still needs to be included. The error is: Error: 'rows' is not a member of 'Knowledge_Academy.DataSetSchedules'.

Comment: Don't iterate the Dataset, Iterate the DataTable DT

Comment: Thanks for all the help. We get this error now using the coding sample: Error 1 Variable 'DR' hides a variable in an enclosing block. What is this hiding? Do we need to define it?

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen seems like variable name DR is used , change DR to NR or any other name within the For Each. or remove this line `Dim dr as DataRow`

Comment: Thanks. So close now. I found the extra "DR" in the dim statement and did not know the for loop re-dimmed it. Anyway all we need to get at is the value in a column called TeacherName but it does not show up in intellisence when entering this based on the coding I got from Google: DR(col.TeacherName). It displays this error: Error 1 'TeacherName' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataColumn'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23643/discussion-between-abzy-and-emad-ud-deen)

Comment: Nothing in these answers is appropriate for *strongly-typed* datasets. code should be eg For each r as DataTableSchedulesrow In dt.rows . .  .